# Entity Framework 4.0 generated entity set vs POCO with INotifyPropertyChanged/IDataErrorInfo

Tags: entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-4

lets assume I do create the entities and I want data binding + error validation in wpf with mvvm pattern. Where is the advance of Poco? POCO is naked and has nothing... no INotifyPropertyChanged or IDataErrorInfo. Due to way much cumbersome work I do not wrap my entities like Customer in CustomerVM/CustomesVM (collection) etc... I return my data in a List<> pass it the ObservableCollection constructor and bind to that collection from the View. Easy and less to code.

So why should I use a POCO which is the super great feature in EF 4.0 so they say...

Answer (score 1):

I 'm learning this new stuff myself, but until now i think the story goes this way: POCO classes spin up (under the hood) their EF equivalent classes which already support Propertychanged  notification.

Comment: seems I must inform myself more to ask properly next time ;-)